# I'm struggling on functions, for example def a (...). What goes in the brackets?

Tags: python

I'm new to programming and I recently started Python (3) in school. I'm having trouble understanding Functions. I've read some examples of Functions for example: def a (...). I understand "def" defines the functions and a names it, but I don't know what goes in the brackets, I heard its a parameter but when I Google it this comes up:

What is a parameter in computing? In computer programming, a parameter is a special kind of variable, used in a subroutine to refer to one of the pieces of data provided as input to the subroutine. These pieces of data are called arguments.

Comment: Please start with the [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arguments, parameters, or input variables go within the brackets. These can be thought of as pieces of data you pass to a function for use within that function.

For (a very basic) example:

```
def plus_five(num):
    my_other_number = num + 5
    return my_other_number
```

This function would take in a number and **within the scope of this function** that number would be known as `num`. A new variable that exists only within this function would be created, named `my_other_number`, initialized to the value of the input `num` plus 5.

The function then returns the value of `my_other_number`.

In usage it would look something like:

```
my_num = 10
returned_number = plus_five(my_num)
print(my_num)
>>> 10
print(returned_number)
>>> 15
```

Think of an argument like you would the variable of a mathematical function:

```
f(x) = x+5
f(10) = 10+5 = 15
```

Comment: Thanks but can you tell me what an argument or a parameter does? Whenever I google it the definition contains other programming terms which I am not aware of.

Comment: I've just added a quick little example that hopefully should explain somewhat what an argument is.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So is this it summarized? 'plus_five' is the name of the function and 'num' is the name of the variable? Oh and also did you make a mistake on the second program because you typed 'my_num' instead of 'num' or are they two completely different programs?

Comment: Yes, you are correct about the name of the function and the name of the passed in variable. However, the names do not have to match. `num` in function declaration is just what that data will be called will within that function. That data is called `my_num` in the main area. It can be a bit tricky, but they both reference the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try with an actual simple example:

```
def sumthis(a,b):
    return a+b

c = sumthis(3,2)
print(c)
```

, a function to sum two numbers. The result (print sends stuff to the console so you are able to see) is: 5

Comment: So it's an input variable?

Comment: @Programmer 2 Exactly! You input 3 and 5 to the function. In this case it will be returned the sum of both numbers to a third variable you might call output.

Answer (score 0):

Functions in programming are similar to functions in algebra. In algebra, functions are represented as `f(x)`. In programming, they are defined using code but the representation is the same.
So if `f(x) = x^2` in algebra, in python, it will be:

```
def f(x):
    return x**2
```

And in algebra, `f(2) = 4`. So, in python `f(2)` will return 4.

Comment: We haven't learn anything about f(2) in Maths yet, does it basically square the number? Thanks

Comment: You haven't learned functions in algebra yet? `f(2)` basically replaces `x` with `2` in `f(x)` and since `f(x)` returns square of `x`, `f(2)` will return square of 2. If `f(x) = x^3`, then it will return cube, and so on depending on what `f(x)` is defined as.

Answer (score 0):

What will probably help you the most is using google in a slightly different manner. Try searching for definitions of things such as:

```
define: programming argument
define: programming parameter
```

these two examples, when searched on google, each line separately, will show you a definition of each term. Any time you use "define" first on google, it will search a definition of the term or phrase that follows.